# It is possible to implement following UI using ListView in JavaFX

Tags: java, listview, javafx

It is possible to implement following UI using ListView in JavaFX:

(Since I do have enough reputation to post a image, it can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5jyH.jpg))

Which means not only the titles, but the dates and status(synced or not) as well.
The information in the ListView should be read form a `ObservableList<CustomObject>`. Each `CustomObject` has its properties including title, date, status, etc...
Finally, I will need to add a listener to it.(This won't be a big issue I think).

Again, thanks very much. Since my level is pretty low and I am possibly asking some stupid questions, I kindly ask you if you can explain with some actual codes.

Or, if a ListView cannot do such a thing, what else should I use?

Comment: Yes exactly the same layout view like in a link, can be done using ListView. You need to provide your own custom ListCell. You can find enough resources here on SO and on the net about using ListView and ListCell. Start coding by referring them, and if you stuck somewhere you ask questions here of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a VBox for the lines?
Then for each entry an other VBox with two entries for the two rows (one for the title and one for the date/status).
Title, date and status -> label

If you want to drag your scene together you can try:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/installation-guide/jfxsb-installation_2_0.htm